# How can I group by in subquery or how can achieve my output

Tags: mysql

This is my query:

```
SELECT dte,((SELECT COUNT(prdt) as P1 FROM table
WHERE prdt LIKE '%P1%' AND stat= 'Done' AND dte  BETWEEN '08/01/2016' AND '09/07/2016') as P1,

(SELECT COUNT(prdt) as P2 FROM table
WHERE prdt LIKE '%P2%' AND stat= 'Done' AND dte  BETWEEN '08/01/2016' AND '09/07/2016') as P2,

(SELECT COUNT(prdt) as P3 FROM table
WHERE prdt LIKE '%P3%' AND stat= 'Done' AND dte  BETWEEN '08/01/2016' AND '09/07/2016') as P3

FROM table WHERE dte BETWEEN '08/01/2016' AND '09/07/2016' GROUP BY dte
```

table

```
+-------------------+
|  dte1  |prdct|stat|
+--------+-----+----+
|8/1/2016|  P1 |Done|
+--------+-----+----+
|8/2/2016|  P2 |Done|
+--------+-----+----+
|8/3/2016|  P1 |Done|
+--------+-----+----+
|8/1/2016|  P3 |Done|
+--------+-----+----+
```

This is what I want output:

```
+--------+----+----+----+
|  Dte1  | P1 | P2 | P3 |
+--------+----+----+----+
|8/1/2016|  1 |NULL|  1 |
+--------+----+----+----+
|8/2/2016|NULL|  1 |NUll|
+--------+----+----+----+
|8/3/2016| 1  |NULL|NULL|
+--------+----+----+----+
```

Comment: You should edit your question and show what you have tried.

Comment: i cant group by every select what can i do to achieve the output that i want?

Comment: Is no one going to mention the elephant in the room? What is a '08/01/2016'? And how can it be between something?

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need subqueries in the SELECT list? There's no need to scan through the table multiple times.

The literals in the `dte BETWEEN` predicate look like they are meant to be `DATE` values. But those aren't in valid format for `DATE` literals. If `dte` column is string type (`CHAR` or `VARCHAR`) and you are storing date values in the `dte` column... you are doing it wrong.

Consider what happens in the query with a `dte` (string) value of `'08/15/1999'` is compared as a string. For example, testing this condition:

```
 SELECT '08/15/1999' BETWEEN '08/01/2016' AND '09/16/2016'
```

evalutes to TRUE. (In terms of string comparisons, that is true. But if we look at those values as dates, it doesn't make sense that a date in 1999 would be between two dates in 2016.)

But setting the the wonky date format issue aside, and address the question you asked...

---

Just write a query using *conditional aggregation*. For example:

```
  SELECT t.dte
       , SUM( t.stat = 'Done' AND t.prdt LIKE '%P1%' ) AS P1
       , SUM( t.stat = 'Done' AND t.prdt LIKE '%P2%' ) AS P2
       , SUM( t.stat = 'Done' AND t.prdt LIKE '%P3%' ) AS P3
    FROM table t
   WHERE t.dte BETWEEN '2016-08-01' AND '2016-09-07'
   GROUP BY t.dte
```

That query will return "zero" counts, which doesn't match the specification. To match the specification, and return NULL values in place of zeros, we can replace the zero counts with NULL, using the convenient `NULLIF` function:

```
  SELECT t.dte
       , NULLIF(SUM( t.stat = 'Done' AND t.prdt LIKE '%P1%' ),0) AS P1
       , NULLIF(SUM( t.stat = 'Done' AND t.prdt LIKE '%P2%' ),0) AS P2
       , NULLIF(SUM( t.stat = 'Done' AND t.prdt LIKE '%P3%' ),0) AS P3
    FROM table t
   WHERE t.dte BETWEEN '2016-08-01' AND '2016-09-07'
   GROUP BY t.dte
```

For a more ANSI-standards compliant version, replace the MySQL shorthand

```
   NULLIF(SUM( t.stat = 'Done' AND t.prdt LIKE '%P1%' ),0)
```

with

```
   SUM( CASE WHEN t.stat = 'Done' AND t.prdt LIKE '%P1%' THEN 1 END )
```

---

If there's some (unfathomable) reason you *need* to use subqueries in the SELECT list, you could use correlated subqueries. Just reference the value of `dte` from the outer query inside the subquery.

```
SELECT t.dte
     , ( SELECT NULLIF(COUNT(*),0)
           FROM table t1
          WHERE t1.dte = t.dte
            AND t1.prdt LIKE '%P1%'
            AND t1.stat = 'Done'
       ) AS P1
     , ( SELECT NULLIF(COUNT(*),0)
           FROM table t2
          WHERE t2.dte = t.dte
            AND t2.prdt LIKE '%P2%'
            AND t2.stat = 'Done'
       ) AS P1
     , ( SELECT NULLIF(COUNT(*),0)
           FROM table t3
          WHERE t3.dte = t.dte
            AND t3.prdt LIKE '%P3%'
            AND t3.stat = 'Done'
       ) AS P3
    FROM table t
   WHERE t.dte BETWEEN '2016-08-01' AND '2016-09-07'
   GROUP BY t.dte
```

Using correlated subqueries in the SELECT list is usually more expensive than using the conditional aggregation pattern. That's because the subquery gets executed for each row returned by the outer query. If the outer query returns a thousand rows, the subquery gets executed a thousand times.